# Hashmap graphing output is wrong

Tags: java, graph, hashmap

I'm working with a text file, where the first column represents the courses, and the other columns are prerequisites for that course.

```
CS1 None
CS2 CS1
CS3 CS2
CS4 CS1
CS5 CS3 CS4
CS6 CS2 CS4
```

I want to go line by line and create a key value of the first index of each line
and the values are the index's after index 0.

For example, line `CS6 CS2 CS4` would  have `CS6` is the key(course) and it's values(prerequisites) would be `CS2, CS4`.

`CS6` would have`CS4` as a neighbor and `CS4` would have `CS2` as its neighbor.

but my output looks like this:

```
CS1:  None, CS1
CS3:  CS2, CS3
CS2:  CS1, CS2
CS5:  CS3, CS5
CS4:  CS1, CS4
CS6:  CS2, CS6
None:
```

I'm trying to get an output like:

```
CS1:
CS3:  CS2
CS2:  CS1
CS5:  CS3, CS4
CS4:  CS1
CS6:  CS2, CS4
```

My constructor(which is giving me the wrong output):

```
public Graph(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // open the file for scanning
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    // create the graph
    graph = new HashMap<String, Node>();

    // loop over and parse each line in the input file
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        // read and split the line into an array of strings
        // where each string is separated by a space.
        Node n1;
        Node n2;
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] fields = line.split(" ");

        // creates new nodes as necessary
        if (graph.containsKey(fields[0])) {
            n1 = graph.get(fields[0]);
        }
        else {
            n1 = new Node(fields[0]);
            graph.put(fields[0], n1);
        }
        if (graph.containsKey(fields[1])) {
                n2 = graph.get(fields[1]);
        }
        else {
            n2 = new Node(fields[1]);
            graph.put(fields[1],  n2);
        }

        n1.addNeighbor(n2);
        n1.addNeighbor(n1);
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

addNeighbor method:

```
/**
 * Add a neighbor to this node.  Checks if already present, and does not
 * duplicate in this case.
 *
 * @param n: node to add as neighbor.
 */
public void addNeighbor(Node n) {
    if(!neighbors.contains(n)) {
        neighbors.add(n);
    }
}
```

...and my Node constructor:

```
/*
 * Neighbors of this node are stored as a list (adjacency list).
 */
private List<Node> neighbors;

/**
 * Constructor.  Initialized with an empty list of neighbors.
 *
 * @param name string representing the name associated with the node.
 */
public Node(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.neighbors = new LinkedList<Node>();
}
```

Edit: I want to use my neighbor way of solving this still, my output results from me printing my map. I just am trying to solve this problem by only changing the constructor and nothing else.

Comment: Well, I don't see a definition of `neighbors` variable, so no idea what's going on there.  But I do see that you process only `n1` and `n2` for each line, which isn't going to work if a line has more than two items.  You need to make a loop there (or something).

Comment: I have it defined above the Node constructor

Comment: Why don't you use a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` or `HashMap<Node, List<Node>>` instead of your neighbour system? It would make more sense to me. Do you use that data structure somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Your data structure is more complicated than it needs to be. And I'd suggest you use a scanner per line as well, not only to get the lines.

Comment: If the output is what is wrong, then could you post the output method?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Find a suitable data structure

Your current data structure seems overly complicated, which probably led you to make mistakes while filling it, and mistakes while iterating on it for display.

#### Simplest

According to your target output, you don't seem to want transitive dependencies in your structure. You only want to output direct children of a course (direct dependencies).

Therefore, your data structure should not really be a graph, but simply a map of each course to its requirements' list:

```
Map<String, List<String>> requirements = new HashMap<>();
```

#### Keeping the graph idea

If you need more complex data or if you actually need transitive dependencies, then you can use a graph of courses, along with a dictionary of existing courses (to reuse the objects). However, I'd suggest in that case that your `Course` class (or Node class if you prefer) contain requirements (children) of the course instead its neighbours.

```
// this is the dictionary, the Node objects themselves contain the dependencies
Map<String, Course> courses = new HashMap<>();

// your Node class (I renamed to make the purpose of the objects more readable)
class Course {
    private List<Course> requirements = new LinkedList<>();

    public Course(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addRequirement(Course n) {
        requirements.add(n);
    }

    public List<Course> getRequirements() {
        return requirements;
    }
}
```

### 2. Solve your problem

You are currently not reading the whole line each time. After getting the first element of your line, you should loop over the others to add them as requirements.

Here, you are only reading indexes 0 and 1 of your array, which should tell you that you're forgetting about potential other requirements.

Also, there is something wrong here:

```
n1.addNeighbor(n2); // why is the 1st requirement a neighbour of his parent?
n1.addNeighbor(n1); // why is the parent a neighbour of himself ?
```